# Laravel stuck cache keeps displaying what's not there

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

So I'm creating a web application and got stuck trying to fix this error

"Use of undefined constant images - assumed 'images' (View: /Users/ernest/Diplomska/bazar/resources/views/pages/welcome.blade.php)"

I used Chrome and Safari to see if the problem was in browser cache. Then I stopped, updated and restarted Valet. After that failed I cleared composer cache and updated it and still nothing. I also tried rebooting the system just in case to no avail.

My current code:

```
    <!-- First row -->
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-1">              
        <a href="#">
          <img src="{{ url('/public/images/literature.jpeg') }}">
          <p>Literature</p>
        </a>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-2">
        <a href="#"> 
          <img src="{{ url('/public/images/music.jpeg') }}">
          <p>Music</p>
         </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-2">
          <a href="#" id="categoryId">
            <img src="{{ url('/public/images/graphics.jpeg') }}">
            <p>Graphics</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

What browser thinks my code is (displayed in error on any browser):

```
    1       <!-- Choose category -->
    2       <div class="container" style="padding-top: 70px; padding-bottom: 70px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d6dbe0;">
    3          <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #a7a7a7; padding-bottom: 40px;">Choose category</h1>
    4          <div style="margin: auto;">
    5    
    6             <!-- First row -->
    7             <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    8               <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-1">              
    9                 <a href="#">
    10                  <img src="<?php echo e(asset(images/literature.jpeg)); ?>">
    11                  <p>Literature</p>
    12                </a>
    13              </div>   
    14              <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-2">
    15                <a href="#"> 
    16                  <img src="public/music.jpeg">
    17                  <p>Music</p>
    18                </a>
    19              </div>
    20              </a>
    21              <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-2">
    22                <a href="#" id="categoryId">
```

So my question is how do I tell browser to recheck the written code because it keeps insisting on asset() which is no longer there.

Comment: `php artisan view:clear` clears the cached view files. Does that help?

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel/Blade uses cache to speed up display of pages. To clear all cached views use

`php artisan view:clear`

from your command line.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are looking at the right file. There might be a different welcome file some place else.
- Use View::render function to see what the output of the file is rather than debugging it on your browser.